How can I get access to the Kafka binder's configuration properties?
I have multiple binder definitions in my Spring Cloud Stream app.
Everything is configured fine and works when I use my bindings and specify the relevant binder.
I can do this to get my binder:
Binder binder = binderFactory.getBinder("my-kafka-binder", Object.class);
KafkaMessageChannelBinder myKafkaBinder = (KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binder;

But I need to get access to the KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties within it so I can dynamically use the properties for the platform testing library.
How can I do this without using reflection? Is there any way this can be made public?
